# Behavior of the adress 0x7e00 in different sectors and their alternatives

Tags: x86, virtualbox, nasm, osdev, bios

I'd like to hear the behavior of 0x7e00 that may differ in other sectors.

All I know is that address is indicating the final byte for the sector 1 *(the code I provided is for demonstration)*

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

; CHS configuration
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 1
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 2
mov dl, 0x00 ; I don't know if that's correct register, I forgot
mov es, [zero]
mov bx, 0x7e00 ; supposedly [es:bx]
int 13h

zero:
  db 0

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0x55AA
times 0x400 - ($-$$) db 0
```

Either it may use the same address as I already configured the CHS values in the top of the code *(after org & bits instruction)*, or...

```
mov cl, 3 ; Sector number
mov bx, 0x7e00? 0xfc00?
```

If not, then I could multiply the hexadecimal value by 2 as I'm two sectors ahead *(or by more if way further)* from the boot one.

Comment: 7E00h is just 7C00h (default location of first boot sector's loader) + 200h (standard sector size). So if you want to load 2 sectors that follow the boot sector (C:H:S = 0:0:1) consecutively you would load the second sector (C:H:S = 0:0:2) to 7E00h and the third sector (C:H:S = 0:0:3) to 7E00h + 200h = 8000h. 0FC00h is a nonsequitur, as 7E00h is not obtained the way you suggest. "I don't know if that's correct register" Correct register to hold the CHS Head value is `dh`. You should preserve `dl` as passed by the ROM-BIOS loader instead. And you should set up `ds` and `ss:sp` before `int 13h`.

Comment: Now I understand that very well, I was too lazy to open my PC, boot VSCode and check the .asm code, haha. I appreciate your help